# Starting HTML5 application programming

Tags: html

I am a middleware programmer having worked on Unix and Windows having used predominantly C and in telecom domain (VoIP, Mobile and Protocols). However, I am well versed with perl and ruby and have exposure to html and javascript.

Now I am starting development on Set Top Box and I am required to develop HTML5 applications because the browser is the dev platform for the STB. Now I need help on how to get started with HTML5 application programming. I have read articles and looked at books on the HTML5 features like video, canvas etc. But I have not come across anything that teaches me the HTML5 app development hands-on. Say "Hello World" example of C.

Probably it might be the initial friction that might holding back from transition from telecom to web programming, though the lines have long been blurred between the domains. To confound the issue, there are so many tons of frameworks and plugins available for development that I have come across such as Sencha, JQuery for DOM, etc.

In short - how do i get started with HTML5 application development? If I need to use any specific frameworks, then pls suggest.

Comment: W3Schools.com is a great place to learn HTML5.

Comment: @Shahzeb thats why: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: "development on Set Top Box and I am required to develop HTML5 applications because the browser is the dev platform for the STB" does that mean the settop boxes of television would run on HTML5?

Comment: yes, I think most of current STB and TVs make use of HTML5. For ex look at samsung smart tv development platform - http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_2/cover_page.html

Answer (score 2):

Some Great Resources for HTML 5:

[HTML5 Cheat Sheet](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/06/html-5-cheat-sheet-pdf/)

[Move The Web Forward](http://movethewebforward.org/)

[HTML5 Readiness](http://html5readiness.com/)

[Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/)

[Google's HTML, CSS, and Javascript from the Ground Up](http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/)

[Opera Web Standards Curriculum](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/1-introduction-to-the-web-standards-cur/#toc)

[SitePoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/) HTML,CSS,JS + Lists of Feature Support

[The Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs) intermediate CSS and excellent JavaScript

and several more...

Comment: so one should avoid the frameworks?

Comment: For frameworks, I believe these may be of help:
[HTML5 and CSS3 Frameworks](http://creativefan.com/html5-css3-framework-choices-15-great-web-frameworks/)
and 
[HTML5 Frameworks for Mobile and Web App Development](http://www.readwriteweb.com/mobile/2012/03/poll-what-company-provides-the.php)